# Delphi - How to check if a DataSet has fetched all rows?

Tags: delphi, dataset, firedac

As title says, is it possible to check if a DataSet has fetched all it rows?
I am using components that descends from FDQuery.

I need it becouse I was sure my DataSets was fetching all rows everytime, but I noticed that changing the connection.FetchOptions.Mode to fmAll (from fmOnDemand), the time they need to open increases by 1.5 multiplier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your q correctly, the documentation answers it:

> ProviderEOF is a shortcut for the TFDDataSet.SourceEOF property and allows you >to specify whether all rows are fetched from a DB.
>
> The property is for the TClientDataSet compatibility.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomMemTable.ProviderEOF

I am obliged to @Victoria for pointing out that SourceEOF is the better way of checking, see

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.SourceEOF

Comment: Thanks, but it is Always false, both with fmAll and fmOnDemand

Comment: Oh.  Perhaps your q will catch @Victoria's attention - she is the FireDAC expert here these days.  Btw, what database back-end are you using?  And which Delphi version?

Comment: Sorry, i think it's becouse i was checking it on a single record DataSet. On others it works

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: `SourceEOF` is the right way, but I cannot easily read that in this answer (in its current state). I would prefer linking to `SourceEOF` property rather than `ProviderEOF`.